# Room Temperature Alarm to Email - Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to send and email based on High temperature or humidity but i cant figure out how to add this. Its my first time using DHT22 with Raspberry Pi so not sure how to structure my code.

I've tried a variety of codes others have suggested but they either no longer work on Python 3 (originally Python 2 - depreciated), or the code I've written just doesn't do anything except monitor and log with no email on high temp.

My original coding so far is this:

```
import os
import time 
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime
import Adafruit_DHT

file = open("/home/pi/TempHumLog.csv", "a")

if os.stat("/home/pi/TempHumLog.csv").st_size == 0:
        file.write("Date,Time,Temperature,Humidity\n")

while True:
    DHT_SENSOR = Adafruit_DHT.DHT22
    DHT_PIN = 4
    temperature, humidity = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(DHT_SENSOR, DHT_PIN)
    file.write("{0},{1},{3:0.2f}*C,{2:0.2f}%rh\n".format(time.strftime("%d/%m/%y"), time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"), temperature, humidity))
    file.flush()
    print("{0},{1},{3:0.2f}*C,{2:0.2f}%rh\n".format(time.strftime("%d/%m/%y"), time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"), temperature, humidity))
    time.sleep(5)
    
import smtplib

  
#Email Variables
SMTP_SERVER = 'smtp.gmail.com' #Email Server (don't change!)
SMTP_PORT = 587 #Server Port (don't change!)
GMAIL_USERNAME = 'example@gmail.com' #change this to match your gmail account
GMAIL_PASSWORD = 'example pw'  #change this to match your gmail password
 
      
class Emailer:
    def sendmail(self, recipient, subject, content):
          
        #Create Headers
        headers = ["From: " + GMAIL_USERNAME, "Subject: " + subject, "To: " + recipient,
                   "MIME-Version: 1.0", "Content-Type: text/html"]
        headers = "\r\n".join(headers)
  
        #Connect to Gmail Server
        session = smtplib.SMTP(SMTP_SERVER, SMTP_PORT)
        session.ehlo()
        session.starttls()
        session.ehlo()
  
        #Login to Gmail
        session.login(GMAIL_USERNAME, GMAIL_PASSWORD)
  
        #Send Email & Exit
        session.sendmail(GMAIL_USERNAME, recipient, headers + "\r\n\r\n" + content)
        session.quit
  
sender = Emailer()
 
while True:
    if temperature > 24:
        sendTo = 'example@gmail.com'
        emailSubject = "High Temp!"
        emailContent = "<br>A High Temp has Activated At: " + time.ctime() + "<br><br>Check The Room Temperature Levels"
        sender.sendmail(sendTo, emailSubject, emailContent)
        print("Email Sent")

    elif temperature < 23:
        sendTo = 'example@gmail.com'
        emailSubject = "Room Temp Healthy"
        emailContent = "High Room Temp Alarm Has Cleared At: " + time.ctime()
        sender.sendmail(sendTo, emailSubject, emailContent)
        print("Email Sent")
   
    time.sleep(5)
```

At this time, no errors come through the terminal but it doesn't send any email. I've tried adding something like this:

```
instance = dht22.DHT22(pin=4)
while True:
     result = instance.read()
     tempHI = 26
     tempLOW = 19
if (result.temperature) > tempHI:
   **Send Email Script**
```

But no luck!

Any ideas how i can get the high temperature to trigger the email?

Comment: Could you ask the question in a simpler form? What is the goal trying to be achieved and have you done any research on the task at hand?

Comment: Hey Redgar, Thanks for the tips. I have editted my question. To simply put it (if still not clear), I want to send an email, if the temperature on the DHT22 goes above 26 Degrees C. I have got it working on a digital input, so when a button is pressed, it sends the email. I just cant get it to work on say "if temperature > 26: Send Email). Hope this is more clear in the post now?